# Ignoring variable assignment in loop, c++

Tags: c++, loops, variable-assignment

In my work I need to calculate permutations product. I store permutations in arrays, like `int g[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};`. It looks like these two snippets give different outputs:

```
for (int r = 0; r < q; r++) {
            myfile << endl << g[(H[a] + r) % q] << g[(H[b] + r) % q] << endl;
        }
```

and

```
for (int r = 0; r < q; r++) {
        a = g[(H[a] + r) % q];
        b = g[(H[b] + r) % q];
        myfile << endl << a << b << endl;
    }
```

Results respectively are: 01
12
23
34
45
56
67
70 and
12
23
34
45
45
56
67
70.
On some steps variable assignment doesn't work. All variables are set before, q is equal to 8.

Could you please explain me why is it so? Thank you!

Comment: Please construct a minimal test-case.

Comment: When you say "it does not work" we don't know what that exactly means. What exactly does not work?  What do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight , thank you, silly question, careless mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example the variables `a` and `b` are not updated and are either uninitialized or is using the values that had been previously initialized outside the loop.

In the second case, the assignments are mutually dependent with an initial seed value and the variables `a` and `b`  gets incrementally updated.